# Power Pages Website vs Power Apps Pages

Tags: office-365, powerapp, power-platform, powerapps-portal, power-pages

[image]

I am new to Power Pages. What is the difference between creating a Power Page from the Power Apps portal and creating a website from the `make.powerpages` website?

Are they the same site or are they separate and being used independently?

[image]

Comment: There is no `make.powerpages` website, only `https://make.powerapps.com/` is available currently.

Comment: I just create a website using make.powerpages.microsoft

Comment: You kinda forgot to add "microsoft.com" to web site URL. Anyway, creating a portal/website from `https://make.powerapps.com/` is same as creating Power  Pages (site) from `https://make.powerpages.microsoft.com/`.

Comment: Thanks, Ganesh, but why the result is different? If I use make.powerpps.com, it won't give me the edit option on the page, and if I use the make.powerpages.microsoft.com, I can edit the website.

Comment: I can see Edit option for both the websites/portals on `https://make.powerpages.microsoft.com/` under "Active sites". Check the image in my answer below.

Comment: But, why I cant see the edit option on the one made in make.powerapps website.

Comment: Are you able to edit it from make.powerapps.com instead of make.powerpages.microsoft.com? Or unable to edit from both sites? What permissions/role you have on the environment?

Comment: Hi Harris, any update on this thread? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my below response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a portal/website from `https://make.powerapps.com/` is same as creating Power  Pages (site) from `https://make.powerpages.microsoft.com/`.

I just created a website from `https://make.powerapps.com/` and it shows up on the `https://make.powerpages.microsoft.com/` portal:

[image]

Power Pages is an evolution of Power Apps Portals. Here are some similarities between Power Apps Portals and Power Pages:

1. Power Pages is built on the foundation of Power Apps Portals providing the same robust capabilities and pro developer experiences with a new low-code maker experience and out-of-the box templates to design modern business sites.
2. Both Power Apps Portals and Power Pages use Microsoft Dataverse as their underlying data structure for makers to manipulate and store data.
3. Makers can build externally facing websites using both Power Apps Portals and Power Pages.

You can find more information at:

1. [Differences between PowerApps Portals and Power Pages](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/differences-between-powerapps-portals-and-power-pages/ba-p/3571229)
2. [What is Power Pages?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-pages/introduction)